# My Neural network is causing a stack overflow

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

It's hard for me to produce a minimal example because I think it's related to some more of my code. However, I believe I've provided the pertinent code below.

I've removed sections of classes etc that I don't think are very important to the problem.

I have a Neural Network class that makes use of Neurons:

**Neuron**

```
template<std::size_t NumInputs>
class Neuron
{
public:
    Neuron()
    {
        for(auto& i : m_inputValues)
            i = 0;
        for(auto& e : m_eligibilityTraces)
            e = 0;
        for(auto& w : m_weights)
            w = 0;
        m_biasWeight = 0;
        m_biasEligibilityTrace = 0;
        m_outputValue = 0;
    }

    void SetInputValue(const std::size_t index, const double value)
    {
        m_inputValues[index] = value;
    }

    void SetWeight(const std::size_t index, const double weight)
    {
        if(std::isnan(weight))
            throw std::runtime_error("Shit! this is a nan bread");
        m_weights[index] = weight;
    }

    void SetBiasWeight(const double weight)
    {
        m_biasWeight = weight;
    }

    double GetInputValue(const std::size_t index) const
    {
        return m_inputValues[index];
    }

    double GetWeight(const std::size_t index) const
    {
        return m_weights[index];
    }

    double GetBiasWeight() const
    {
        return m_biasWeight;
    }

    double CalculateOutput()
    {
        double m_outputValue = 0;
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < NumInputs; ++i)
        {
            m_outputValue += m_inputValues[i] * m_weights[i];
        }
        m_outputValue += 1.0 * m_biasWeight;
        m_outputValue = sigmoid(m_outputValue);
        return m_outputValue;
    }

    double GetOutput() const
    {
        return m_outputValue;
    }

    double GetEligibilityTrace(const std::size_t index) const
    {
        return m_eligibilityTraces[index];
    }

    void SetEligibilityTrace(const std::size_t index, const double eligibility)
    {
        m_eligibilityTraces[index] = eligibility;
    }

    void SetBiasEligibility(const double eligibility)
    {
        m_biasEligibilityTrace = eligibility;
    }

    double GetBiasEligibility() const
    {
        return m_biasEligibilityTrace;
    }

private:
    std::array<double,NumInputs> m_inputValues;
    std::array<double,NumInputs> m_weights;
    std::array<double,NumInputs> m_eligibilityTraces;
    double m_biasWeight;
    double m_biasEligibilityTrace;
    double m_outputValue;
};
```

**Neural Network**

```
template<std::size_t NumInputs, std::size_t NumHidden, std::size_t NumOutputs>
class NeuralNetwork
{
public:

...

    std::array<double,NumOutputs> FeedForward(const std::array<double,NumInputs>& inputValues)
    {
        for(auto& hiddenNeuron : m_hiddenNeurons)
        {
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i < NumInputs; ++i)
                hiddenNeuron.SetInputValue(i,inputValues[i]);

            hiddenNeuron.CalculateOutput();
        }

        std::array<double, NumOutputs> returnValue;

        for(std::size_t h = 0; h < NumHidden; ++h)
        {
            auto hiddenOutput = m_hiddenNeurons[h].GetOutput();
            for(std::size_t o = 0; o < NumOutputs; ++o)
                m_outputNeurons[o].SetInputValue(h, hiddenOutput);
        }

        for(std::size_t o = 0; o < NumOutputs; ++o)
        {
            returnValue[o] = m_outputNeurons[o].CalculateOutput();
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

private:

    std::array<Neuron<NumInputs>,NumHidden> m_hiddenNeurons;
    std::array<Neuron<NumHidden>,NumOutputs> m_outputNeurons;
};
```

Everything works fine for a `NeuralNetwork<86,86,2>` but after considering that I need some more input variables, i.e. `NeuralNetwork<170,170,2>` the `FeedForward` method produces a Stack Overflow when I've enabled `-O2` compiler flag. It doesn't produce this issue with `-g` flag set.

If I remove this section of the `FeedForward` method, I don't get the stack overflow:

```
for(std::size_t h = 0; h < NumHidden; ++h)
{
    auto hiddenOutput = m_hiddenNeurons[h].GetOutput();
    for(std::size_t o = 0; o < NumOutputs; ++o)
        m_outputNeurons[o].SetInputValue(h, hiddenOutput);
}
```

I can't understand why this is producing a stack overflow. The number of hidden units is 170, the number of output units is 2; surely this isn't enough to cause an overflow, especially considering that above I looped through 170 input to 170 hidden units.

As you can see in the `Neuron` class, the `GetOutput()` method doesn't involve any other function calls, `SetInputValue()` doesn't do anything like that either. There's no recursion.

The removed section works fine without the inner loop. But then the loop outside of it below causes the stack overflow.

I.e. this causes a stack overflow:

```
for(std::size_t h = 0; h < NumHidden; ++h)
{
    auto hiddenOutput = m_hiddenNeurons[h].GetOutput();
   // for(std::size_t o = 0; o < NumOutputs; ++o)
     //   m_outputNeurons[o].SetInputValue(h, hiddenOutput);
}

for(std::size_t o = 0; o < NumOutputs; ++o)
{
    returnValue[o] = m_outputNeurons[o].CalculateOutput();
}
```

Whereas this doesn't:

```
for(std::size_t h = 0; h < NumHidden; ++h)
{
    auto hiddenOutput = m_hiddenNeurons[h].GetOutput();
   // for(std::size_t o = 0; o < NumOutputs; ++o)
     //   m_outputNeurons[o].SetInputValue(h, hiddenOutput);
}

for(std::size_t o = 0; o < NumOutputs; ++o)
{
    //returnValue[o] = m_outputNeurons[o].CalculateOutput();
}
```

Which makes no sense because the loops aren't nested...

Comment: What's the typical value of `NumOutputs`? `returnValue` is allocated on the stack, so if that's big enough it'll cause your issue. In your "doesn't" example, since you never write to it, `returnValue` might be optimized away.

Comment: `NumOutputs` is 2

Comment: Also: are you allocating the network on the stack or the heap? That's a BIG class, so you might not have much stack left by the time you reach that point in the first place.

Comment: I'm allocating on the stack. But you know why, I just realised I was making a copy of it that was unnecessary in another part of the code. That second local stack variable should have been deleted by this point where I call `FeedForward` but removing it seems to resolve the issue.

In future, I'll allocate this big shit on the heap

Comment: On Windows, the default max. stack size is 1MB per thread. Your `NeuralNetwork<170,170,2>` is already greater than 700,000 bytes in my calculation. I recommend a heap allocation like `std::make_unique<NeuralNetwork<170, 170, 2>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack overflow is only detected on the first ***actual*** write outside the stack boundaries, respectively when actually hitting the guard page. Since you are initializing everything in your `Neuron` class with 0, this makes your `Neuron` initially all Nullbytes. Which matches exactly what your environment has initialized the memory to (not actually initialized, but maps to a shared read only page which only contains Nullbytes).

Once the first non null byte is written to the guard page, it triggers a page fault (shared null page gets replaced by a real page in RAM, if it was legal to write to the address). As a result, the stack overflow is then detected, as this address was not supposed to be written to.

In your case, you had actually long left the stack, and everything following the allocation did already collide with the heap. You just didn't notice, as the guard didn't trigger and was entirely skipped.

Mapping a null page below the valid stack region, rather than leaving a read protected guard page or leaving it entirely unmapped is environment specific.

Having stack and heap that close together, that you can actually jump the guard pages entirely, with a large enough allocation, is also environment specific. Depending on which compiler you use, you can catch this fault with an option which forces stack allocations to happen incrementally, at most one page at a time. (E.g. `-fstack-check` for GCC.)

Use a tool like Valgrind which sets up a more defensive environment to catch such error more easily. This would then already trigger at creation of the arrays, rather than only on the first non zero write.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Neuron class is a "large class object" creating that on the heap might be a better solution, also the containing objects would be too. Something of this nature:

---

- The object that uses or manages the NeuralNetwork could contain a `std::unique_ptr<T>` of that NeuralNetwork object: If other outside class
  objects needs direct access to this then you can simply change it to a
  `std::shared_ptr<T>`
- The NeuralNetwork itself may contain a large sum of Neuron objects within its multiple containers. Again here we can use smart containers but in this case I think it would be a safer bet to use `std::shared_ptr<T>` within the `std::array<>` containers as these Neurons might need to be accessed by other classes as well. If these Neurons are managed and fully contained within the NeuralNetwork class and there is only 1 available NeuralNetwork object then `std::unique_ptr<T>` will work. I'd work with `std::shared_ptr<T>` in this class in case one wants to have multiple NeuralNetwork objects that are sharing resources of Neurons.
- The Neuron Class object itself appears to be fine as is from the source code
  that you've provided.

---

```
// Some object that uses NeuralNetwork
#include <memory>
#include <std::container(s)>
#include "NeuralNetwork.h";

class SomeClass {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<NeuralNetwork> neuralNetwork;

    // ....
};
```

---

```
// NeuralNetwork
#include <memory>
#include <std::container(s)>
#include "Neuron.h"

template<std::size_t NumInputs, std::size_t NumHidden, std::size_t NumOutputs>    
class NeuralNetwork {
private:
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<Neuron<NumInputs>>,NumHidden> m_hiddenNeurons;
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<Neuron<NumHidden>>,NumOutputs> m_outputNeurons;

    // ...
};
```

---

```
// Neuron
// #include <Memory> // Shouldn't be needed
#include <std::container(s)>

template<std::size_t NumInputs>
class Neuron {
private:
    std::array<double,NumInputs> m_inputValues;
    std::array<double,NumInputs> m_weights;
    std::array<double,NumInputs> m_eligibilityTraces;

    double m_biasWeight;
    double m_biasEligibilityTrace;
    double m_outputValue;

    // ...
};
```

---

This should help to do away with the stack overflow.